# How to trigger Unit Tests on ClearCase check in

Tags: unit-testing, clearcase

The testing framework I'm writing includes templates for users to write their own tests. These tests have two modes, one for setting up their related files, and one for verifying those files. When users write their test, they must run the test in setup once to generate those files, but then I want to make sure they don't check in tests that are still in setup.

I can assert a test failure in the setup, but how can I trigger the unit tests at checkin and prevent checking in if any of the tests fail?

Is there a better way to prevent users from checking in files in a specific configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a trigger to run the unit tests at checkin and block checkin if the tests fail.   I would run the tests against test scripts which are already in ClearCase or someone could create their own local version of the test which is easy to pass (return true).

Another method would be to allow checkin and only fire the trigger upon delivery.  That way the user can checkpoint their code but when they deliver it for others to use the unit tests would need to pass before allowing deliver completion.